# why my image position is not positioned randomly even random function is working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I am trying to make a matching game, where left hand side and right hand side the image is positioned randomly. Even after using the random function which is working properly(checked by using console.log) my images are appearing in a line(not appearing randomly).

My javascript, css and html code snippet is written below....

```js
var numberOfFaces=5;
var theLeftSide=document.getElementById("leftSide");
var imgHeight=80;
var imgWidth=80;

function generateFaces(){

while(numberOfFaces>0){
var smileImg=document.createElement("img");

smileImg.src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
smileImg.style.height=imgHeight + "px";
smileImg.style.width=imgWidth + "px";
var randomTop=Math.random() * 400;
randomTop=Math.floor(randomTop);
console.log(randomTop);
var randomLeft=Math.random() * 500;
randomLeft=Math.floor(randomLeft);
console.log(randomLeft);
smileImg.style.top= randomTop + "px";
smileImg.style.left=randomLeft + "px";
leftSide.appendChild(smileImg);
numberOfFaces--;
}

}
```

```css
body{
margin:50px;

}
p{
text-align:center;
font-size:18px;
}

#outer{
border:0.5px solid black;
position:realtive;
height:500px;
margin:20px;
}


#rightSide,#leftSide{
width:500px;
height:500px;
position:absolute;
}

#rightSide{
 left:700px;
 border-left:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MatchingGame.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="MatchingGame.js" ></script>
<title>Matching Game</title>
</head>
<body onload="generateFaces()">
<p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left side.</p>
<div id="outer">
<div id="leftSide"></div>
<div id="rightSide"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: off topic: check `leftSide` and `theLeftSide` in your JS

Comment: @Thomas: Nice catch. Isha, if you're wondering why that wasn't an error, it's because browsers create automatic global variables for elements with IDs, where the variable name is the ID and its value is a reference to the element (like the one you get from `getElementById`). There are good reasons not to rely on that, though. But it's why the above wasn't failing.

Comment: @Thomas : thanks for pointing out my stupid mistake...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks...got the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Because by default, `img` elements are `inline`, and so their `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` are ignored.

If you want to position the elements, use one of the other display modes, such as `position: absolute` which positions them absolutely relative to their offset container. (In your case, the offset container is `#leftSide`.) Perhaps with this rule:

```
#leftSide img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Example:

```js
var numberOfFaces=5;
var theLeftSide=document.getElementById("leftSide");
var imgHeight=80;
var imgWidth=80;

function generateFaces(){

while(numberOfFaces>0){
var smileImg=document.createElement("img");

smileImg.src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
smileImg.style.height=imgHeight + "px";
smileImg.style.width=imgWidth + "px";
var randomTop=Math.random() * 400;
randomTop=Math.floor(randomTop);
console.log(randomTop);
var randomLeft=Math.random() * 500;
randomLeft=Math.floor(randomLeft);
console.log(randomLeft);
smileImg.style.top= randomTop + "px";
smileImg.style.left=randomLeft + "px";
leftSide.appendChild(smileImg);
numberOfFaces--;
}

}
```

```css
body{
margin:50px;

}
p{
text-align:center;
font-size:18px;
}

#outer{
border:0.5px solid black;
position:realtive;
height:500px;
margin:20px;
}


#rightSide,#leftSide{
width:500px;
height:500px;
position:absolute;
}

#rightSide{
 left:700px;
 border-left:2px solid black;
}

#leftSide img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MatchingGame.css" media="screen" />
<title>Matching Game</title>
</head>
<body onload="generateFaces()">
<p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left side.</p>
<div id="outer">
<div id="leftSide"></div>
<div id="rightSide"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MatchingGame.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Note also that I moved the `script` tag to the *end* of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag. Where it was (up at the top), it runs too soon, before the elements it tries to find with `getElementById` are created, so `var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");` returns `null`. But at the end, the element has been created, and it returns the element.